# MySQL CASE with GROUP BY count

Tags: mysql, group-by, case

I have these three queries

```
SELECT COUNT(question_id) AS correct_count, uID FROM mytable  WHERE id
>= 0 AND id <= 1000 AND correct = 1 AND answer_id IS NOT NULL GROUP BY user_id


SELECT COUNT(question_id) AS incorrect_count, uID FROM mytable  WHERE id >= 0 AND id <= 1000 AND correct !=1 AND answer_id IS NOT NULL GROUP BY user_id

SELECT COUNT(question_id) AS null_count, uID FROM mytable  WHERE id >= 0 AND id <= 1000 AND answer_id IS NULL GROUP BY user_id
```

How can I join this as a single query using CASE or IF ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_id, 
       sum(id >= 0 AND id <= 1000 AND correct = 1 AND answer_id IS NOT NULL) AS correctCnt, 
       sum(id >= 0 AND id <= 1000 AND correct !=1 AND answer_id IS NOT NULL) AS incorrectCnt,
       sum(id >= 0 AND id <= 1000 AND answer_id IS NULL) as nullCnt
FROM mytable  
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: This might work , but it is giving me a timeout as the table is very large

Answer (score 0):

`count` only counts non-`null` items, so you could convert the `where` clauses to `case` expressions that return `null` when they do not match:

```
SELECT   user_id,
         COUNT (CASE WHEN id >= 0 AND id <= 1000 AND correct = 1 AND answer_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL) AS correct_count, 
         COUNT (CASE WHEN id >= 0 AND id <= 1000 AND correct !=1 AND answer_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL) AS incorrect_count,
         COUNT (CASE WHEN WHERE id >= 0 AND id <= 1000 AND answer_id IS NULL) AS null_count
FROM     mytable  
GROUP BY user_id
```

Note that all these case statements share some conditions, so those could be extracted to a `where` clause:

```
SELECT   user_id,
         COUNT (CASE WHEN correct = 1 AND answer_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL) AS correct_count, 
         COUNT (CASE WHEN correct !=1 AND answer_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL) AS incorrect_count,
         COUNT (CASE WHEN WHERE answer_id IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL) AS null_count
FROM     mytable
WHERE    id >= 0 AND id <= 1000  
GROUP BY user_id
```